# Prevent image overlay in image view swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a tableViewCell with image view.

Even though I clear the imageView and set the image I get the below unintended behaviour, where one image is overlaid over the other.

[image]

Please advice how this could be resolved.

**Code on Resetting Image in ImageView:**

```
self.profileImageLabelTVCell.cellImageView.image     = nil   // Clearing previous image
self.profileImageLabelTVCell.cellImageView.image     = image
```

Here is the link for the tableViewCell code and roundedImageView class, that I've used. (Since SO did not allow the entire code to be posted here)

https://gist.github.com/pravishanth/14cdb8bf14dd8899b081bdc97988b985

Comment: Where do you call the code to reset the image?

Comment: @MoAbdul-Hameed, In the tableView function cellFoRowAt

Answer (score 1):

Add your reset image code to the `TableViewCell`'s

`func prepareForReuse()` method.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    cellImageView.image = nil
}
```